# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util' for python 3.9 as it is already installed for 3.8.10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip, distutils

I am attempting to install the package pyminizip, but i get the error stating distutils.util module is missing and when attempting the fixes I found online when updating distutils it simply states I already have the newest version. I am using WSL and would love an answer that can solve my problem. Thanks in advance.
See full errors here:

```
sudo pip3 install pyminizip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==20.0.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 490, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2854, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2445, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2451, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 19, in <module>
    from distutils.util import strtobool
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'

teunbergsma@DESKTOP-7IC0BEP:~/ITRL/1ITRL$ sudo apt-get install python3.9-distutils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'python3-distutils' instead of 'python3.9-distutils'
python3-distutils is already the newest version (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 400 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score -1):

`pip uninstall python3-distutils` and then `pip install --pre python3.8-distutils` should solve it